# Laravel Sail Docker MySQL not connecting

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker

I am trying to access a database through an laravel app that is being deployed through a docker container but for some reason I get the following message:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
SELECT * FROM `posts`
```

The database has a table named posts and I'm trying to access from localhost/posts.

The blade template for /posts is the following:

```
@extends('app')
@section('content')
    <h1>Posts index page</h1>
    @forelse ($posts as $post)
        <h2>{{ $post->title }}</h2>
    @empty
        <h2>No posts!</h2>
    @endforelse
@endsection
```

The Route in web.php responsible for /posts is this one:

```
Route::resource('/posts', PostController::class)->only(['index', 'store']);
```

And the index function of the PostController is this one:

```
public function index()
    {
        $posts = Post::all();
        return view('posts.index', compact('posts'));
    }
```

My .env file looks like this:

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:1HEk/HaN8IL/wV8q4DCzpvmM/cYRDvGAIe+0DxS9ggo=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3307
DB_DATABASE=laravel_essentials_app
DB_USERNAME=sail
DB_PASSWORD=password

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
FILESYSTEM_DISK=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

MEMCACHED_HOST=memcached

REDIS_HOST=redis
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailhog
MAIL_PORT=1025
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="hello@example.com"
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=
AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT=false

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_HOST=
PUSHER_PORT=443
PUSHER_SCHEME=https
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
VITE_PUSHER_HOST="${PUSHER_HOST}"
VITE_PUSHER_PORT="${PUSHER_PORT}"
VITE_PUSHER_SCHEME="${PUSHER_SCHEME}"
VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

My docker-compose.yml file looks like this:

```
# For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/sail
version: '3'
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.1
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.1/app
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
            - '${VITE_PORT:-5173}:${VITE_PORT:-5173}'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
            - redis
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql/mysql-server:8.0'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3307}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "${DB_HOST}"
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
            
        volumes:
            - 'sail-mysql:/var/lib/mysql'
            - './vendor/laravel/sail/database/mysql/create-testing-database.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/10-create-testing-database.sh'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-p${DB_PASSWORD}"]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
    redis:
        image: 'redis:alpine'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_REDIS_PORT:-6379}:6379'
        volumes:
            - 'sail-redis:/data'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sail-mysql:
        driver: local
    sail-redis:
        driver: local
```

My operating system is Windows 11 and I'm running MySQL Workbench on it. That is why I am exposing 3307 port instead of 3306.

With the current setup I can run php artisan migrate without a problem from wsl terminal.

What can I do in order to access posts from localhost/posts without getting Connection refused error?

**SOLUTION**
Solved it by changing DB_HOST=mysql in .env but also the DB_PORT to 3306.

**EDITED .env**

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel_essentials_app
DB_USERNAME=sail
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

Comment: Can you post the output of ``docker ps``

Answer (score 2):

Use `mysql` as DB_HOST value in your .env file

Comment: If I do that I get ```Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for mysql failed: Name or service not known (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = laravel_essentials_app and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')``` error when I run php artisan migrate.